# Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <table> [ReactJS]; Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I can see the table on the screen and all the information from the db.json is imported. When I open console it shows me these errors: Text nodes cannot appear as a child of `<table>` [ReactJS]; Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
I tried changing div to fragment but it isn't working.
How can I solve this?

```
return (
  <div className='container'>
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <tr className='bg-dark text-white'>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Product Number</th>
          <th scope="col">Color</th>
          <th scope="col">List Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Modified Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>  
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {products.map((product, index) => (
          <tr>
            <th scope='row'> {index + 1}</th>
            <td>{product.name}</td>   
            <td>{product.number}</td> 
            <td>{product.color}</td> 
            <td>{product.price}</td> 
            <td>{product.date}</td> 
            <td>
              <Link className='btn btn-primary m-2'><i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link>
              <Link className='btn btn-otline-primary m-2'>Edit</Link>
              <Link className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Delete</Link>
            </td> 
          </tr>
        ))};
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <Link className='btn btn-outline-dark w-25' to='/product/add'>
      Add Product
    </Link>
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Text nodes cannot appear as a child of `<table>`

There is a trailing semi-colon at the end of the `tbody` element, out there on it's own. Remove this.

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr className='bg-dark text-white'>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Product Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Color</th>
      <th scope="col">List Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Modified Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
      <tr>
        <th scope='row'> {index + 1}</th>
        <td>{product.name}</td>   
        <td>{product.number}</td> 
        <td>{product.color}</td> 
        <td>{product.price}</td> 
        <td>{product.date}</td> 
        <td>
          <Link className='btn btn-primary m-2'><i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></Link>
          <Link className='btn btn-otline-primary m-2'>Edit</Link>
          <Link className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Delete</Link>
        </td> 
      </tr>
    ))}; // <-- remove trailing text node
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

When mapping an array to JSX the outer-most mapped element needs a React key. The React key should be unique among the siblings. `id` and other GUIDs properties make for great React keys, but the array index is ok as a fallback so long as the array isn't being mutated.

Example:

```
<tbody>
  {products.map((product, index) => (
    <tr key={product.id}> // <-- React key on outer element
      <th scope='row'>{index + 1}</th>
      <td>{product.name}</td>   
      <td>{product.number}</td> 
      <td>{product.color}</td> 
      <td>{product.price}</td> 
      <td>{product.date}</td> 
      <td>
        <Link className='btn btn-primary m-2'>
          <i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" />
        </Link>
        <Link className='btn btn-otline-primary m-2'>Edit</Link>
        <Link className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Delete</Link>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more details/information on React key usage.

Answer (score 1):

When using `map()`, you have to give the immediate mapped Element a unquie `key` so that React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

It needs to be unquiq among its siblings.

```html
{products.map((product, index) => (
   <tr key={ product.name}>  <!-- NEW -->

   </tr>
))}
```

#### Referene:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys